# why do DOCX documents open in protected view if they can't run macros

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, macros

There are 2 kinds of Microsoft word documents. DOCX (documents that can't run macros), and DOCM (documents that can run macros.) Whenever I Download and open a DOCX document anywhere on the internet, it tells me I'm in protected view and warns me that internet files can contain viruses. Why does it need to open in protected view if DOCX documents can't run macros?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it need to open in protected view if DOCX documents can't run
> macros?

Macros do not present the only way to create virused or dangerous documents.

Embedded links that may lead to viruses and even ransomware can also be part of Word documents.

Some graphics can contain hidden links.

The warning is just saying "Careful - Use care"

Comment: So can embedded links lead to a URL where the virus is downloaded, or does the link lead to actual virus code?

Comment: It is possible,yes.  Same with Links in a file.